# jCarousel does not work until the "resize" event is triggered (IE9, IE11)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

I use [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) plugin, and it works like a charm, except that in IE9 && IE11 in a bootstrap modal this carousel does not work untill I trigger a 'resize' event.

I added this code to fix this behaviour.

```
 $('.carousel-control')......one('click', function() { $(window).trigger('resize'); })
```

What's the reason for it and how to fix it better?